# How to read a directory outside of current directory with PHP opendir?

Tags: php

I cannot seem to get the bolded file path to work. I would like the script to scan Dir_3. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
 <?php

  // These files will be ignored
  $excludedFiles = array (
'excludeMe.file',
'excludeMeAs.well'
);

// These file extensions will be ignored
$excludedExtensions = array (
  'html',
'xslt',
'htm',
'ahk',
'xsl',
'txt',
'xml'
);

// Make sure we ignore . and ..
$excludedFiles = array_merge($excludedFiles,array('.','..')); 

 // Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
 for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] =        
 strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i],'.'));
  for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] =    
 strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);

  // Loop through directory
  $count = 0;
  if ($handle = opendir('**http://www.mydomain.com/Dir_1/Dir_2/Dir_3/**')) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  $extn = explode('.',$file);
  $extn = array_pop($extn);
  // Only echo links for files that don't match our rules
  if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) &&   
  !in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)) {
    $count++;
    print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
  }
}
echo '<br /><br /><a href="..">Return</a>';
closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot 'opendir' a URL. But you can specify relative and absolute PATHS in opendir:

```
opendir('.') // open current directory
opendir('..') // open parent directory
opendir('childdir') // open the 'childdir' directory which exists in the current directory (.)
opendir('childdir/grandchilddir') // open a grandchild directory down two levels from the current dir
opendir('../brotherdir') // open a directory next to the current one
opendir('../brotherdir/nephewdir') // open a director next to and down one
opendir('../..') // open a grandparent directory
opendir('../../uncle') // yada yada yada

opendir('/') // open the root dir (primordial slime/adam, depending on your viewpoint)
opendir('/cain') // open a dir called "cain" which is housed in the root directory.
```

Comment: Great that helped out a lot. Thank you very much. The only problem now is that the link that it spits back on the page does not link up properly. Do I have to adjust the path somewhere else to have it link up properly?

Comment: Well, web-based paths can be quite different from what's on the file system. What works for opendir()/fopen()/etc... may have absolutely no relationship to how those directories are mapped in the web site.

Answer (score 1):

`opendir()` supports only proper filesystem paths, not `http://` paths.

Comment: If you have access to the other site you can use [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php)